# Deserialize this Json Object using Jackson?

Tags: json, jackson, jackson-databind

I have been trying to deserialize the data received from [this API](https://bintray.com/statistics/packageGeoStats?&pkgPath=/openmrs/owa/openmrs-owa-conceptdictionary):

```json
{
  "result": "success",
  "timestamp": 1521038012878,
  "data": {
    "GB": 14,
    "DE": 2,
    "US": 2
  },
  "totalIsPublic": true,
  "advanced": false,
  "totalDownloads": {
    "GB": 14,
    "DE": 2,
    "US": 2
  }
}
```

Here is the POJO class:

```java
public class BintrayDownloadCounts {

    private List<Integer> totalDownloads = new ArrayList<>();

    @JsonProperty("totalDownloads")
    public List<Integer> getTotalDownloads() {
        return totalDownloads;
    }

    public void setTotalDownloads(List<Integer> totalDownloads) {
        this.totalDownloads = totalDownloads;
    }
}
```

When I tried deserializing using :

```java
downloadCounts = mapper.readValue(json, BintrayDownloadCounts.class);
```

I get this error:

```
 com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Can not deserialize instance of java.lang.Integer out of START_OBJECT token
```

I have seen many questions containing this error but I am unable to figure out a solution for this particular use case. It may be noted that the `totalDownloads` object is dynamic i.e. its contents are not constant.

Comment: Let me know if my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49280543/1426227) works for you.

Comment: Works beautifully, thanks a ton! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `totalDownloads` property is not an array, so it cannot be mapped to a `List<Integer>`. Use `Map<String, Integer>` instead and ensure that you tell Jackson to ignore the properties that are not mapped to avoid mapping errors:

```java
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class BintrayDownloadCounts {

    @JsonProperty("totalDownloads")
    private Map<String, Integer> totalDownloads;

    public Map<String, Integer> getTotalDownloads() {
        return totalDownloads;
    }

    public void setTotalDownloads(Map<String, Integer> totalDownloads) {
        this.totalDownloads = totalDownloads;
    }
}
```

Then you are good to go:

```java
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
BintrayDownloadCounts downloadCounts = mapper.readValue(json, BintrayDownloadCounts.class);
```